# How can I remove the 4 leaved icon and malware bytes icons in my macOS menu bar?

Tags: macos, icon, menu-bar

I have two annoying icons in my menu bar.

The first I have no clue at all. If I try to click on it, the pointer changes to the "waiting coloured ball".
The second one relates to Malwarebytes that I deleted for I didn't trust.
I would like these two "intruders" out of my way.

[image: two unwanted macOS menu bar icons - m for malware bytes and a four particle / petal icon]

Does anybody know how to find the second app and properly remove both?

Comment: The first icon looks like [Google Photos Backup](https://photos.google.com/apps).

Comment: For Malwarebytes, have you uninstalled the application?  For the pinwheel, did you look in Finder under `Applications` to see any applications you don't recognize?

Comment: Thanks @fsb, the pinwheel looks the same icon as Google Photos Backup, does it have to stay inn the menu bar? I believe I uninstalled Malwarebytes since it is no longer available, however I still received offers for the upgraded version

Comment: Thanks @Ghalid, indeed it looks the same icon as Google Photos Backup, however I only not have Google Photos on my iPad and iPhone, not in the MacBookPro.

Comment: @Ghalid, sorry I mean I only have Google Photos on the iPad and iPhone, I do not have it in my desk top Mac

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to remove the icons from the menu bar, you can ⌘-Click the icons and then drag them out of the menu bar, one at a time. Be sure to drag them down far enough so a little ⓧ icon appears on the cursor.

However, that doesn't uninstall whatever application put them in the menu bar in the first place. If you want to uninstall the original application, you'll need to figure where the menu bar items came from.

You can use the Accessibility Inspector tool to start to understand which applications originally installed the menu bar icons. Follow the instructions from this [Ask Different Q&A](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/143634/how-to-identify-application-of-hung-menu-bar-icon) for how to use Accessibility Inspector. Essentially, it comes down to:

1. Clicking the crosshair/reticle button in the toolbar [image: reticle button]
2. Clicking the menu bar icon in question
3. Clicking `SHOW` in the Accessibility Inspector's *Hierarchy* section

From there, you should be able to search around online for instructions on how to uninstall a specific application.

Comment: Thanks your help.
I have tried your suggestion however Malawarebytes icon keeps coming back.

Comment: @ManuelBaptista See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309674/how-to-remove-malwarebytes-from-mac for how to uninstall Malwarebytes.